# C# (ASP .NET) deserialization exception

Tags: c#, asp.net, json, angularjs, serialization

I'm learning to use ASP.NET MVC with AngularJS.

First we can have a look at my AngularJS code that performs a POST request on the server:

```
$http({
                method: 'POST',
                url: '/Test/PostForm',
                dataType: "json",
                headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8;' },
                data: $.param({
                    data: JSON.stringify($scope.productos),   
                }, true)
            })
            .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(data);
            })
            .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
                console.log(data, status, headers, config);
            })
```

Where:

`$scope.productos = [ {desc:"Product 1", cant: 10, cu:100}, {desc:"Product 2", cant: 10, cu:100} ...]`

I decided to use the `JSON.stringify` method on my `$scope.productos` to pass it to my action as shown below:

```
public JsonResult PostForm(string data)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(data);
        Dictionary<string, string> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(data); // Exception thrown here
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("-------------------");
        
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("-------------------");
        string[] arr = { "Success", "Los archivos han sido agregados correctamente" };
        return Json(arr, JsonRequestBehavior.DenyGet);
    }
```

My problem comes when trying to execute `Dictionary<string, string> values = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, string>>(data);` as I get an exception:

> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,System.String]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
>
> To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.

Any idea on how to fix it? It should be getting a valid JSON string since I'm not getting any errors on JSON.stringify on my .cshtml.

What I'm trying to do is to `unpack` my string content into an array or dictionary.

Comment: what does data look like when it's inside the function?

Comment: Using `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(data);` prints `[{"descripcion":"producto 1","cantidad":250,"unitario":250,"$$hashKey":"object:3"}]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to define a class to deserialize your JSON string into. For example:

```
public class Producto 
{
     [JsonProperty("desc")]
     public string Descripcion{get;set;}

     [JsonProperty("cant")]
     public int Cantidad{get;set;}

     [JsonProperty("cu")]
     public int CostoPorUnidad{get;set;}
}
```

Then you can deserialize your `data` string into an array of `Producto`:

```
var productos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Producto[]>(data);
```

Or into a dictionary, by using some LINQ:

```
var productos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Producto[]>(data).ToDictionary(p=>p.Descripcion);
```

Comment: Works like a charm! I want to read again over `JsonConvert` documentation to understand it better but you sure gave me a good starting point. Thanks a lot @Diego